# the meaning of Contains(@"""")) in c#

Tags: c#, java, contains

A string `strChkQoutes` is

```
IF(H15:H119=\"y\",IF(G15:G119=\"y\",1,0)
```

The following value is true(c#).

```
strChkQoutes.Contains(@"""")
```

I don't understand it's meaning. If I want to convert it to java, the string `strChkQoutes` is

```
IF(H15:H119="y",IF(G15:G119="y",1,0)
```

the following value is false(java).

```
strChkQoutes.contains("\"\"")
```

what is the difference of the contains function in .net and in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference here doesn't lie in the methods, but the strings you're passing to the methods.

In C# verbatim string literals, `@""""` really means one double quote character. The first inner `"` escapes the second inner `"`, since you can't use backslashes for escaping. [Reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

If you didn't use a verbatim string literal, the C# call would look like this:

```
strChkQuotes.Contains("\"")
```

Which is different from your Java string, which contains *two* escaped double quotes in a row and so causes `contains()` to return false.

Answer (score 1):

`@` is a C# String literal that java does not have. In Java you'd have to escape your string: `.contains("\"")`. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for how @-literals are resolved.